# Java web app: Receiving file bytes from REST request and and saving it on client`s machine using browser download dialog

Tags: java, apache, rest, servlets, http-headers

**My goal:** using external REST service, Java web application outputs document list. After user presses on any document, inside of document download servlet other REST request gets content of this document and should force download dialog in browser so user will recieve file to his PC.
**Short technical task:** using file structure that is recieved from REST request, download it to user`s PC using browser download dialog.

**Libraries used:** APACHE HTTP Component

1. When user have clicked on specific document, app is connecting to external REST service and getting back document in InputStream format. Function getDocumentRequest does this job for me and from what i see - everything works 
   great as soon as i see it gives me back file content.
2. When I`m trying to manipulate file content to make output in outputStream I receive error:

   ```
           SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [org.MY_COMPANY.portal.FileDownloadServlet] in context with path [/External_Portal] threw exception
           org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 11309; received: 0
           at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:178)
           at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
           at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:148)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:175)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:146)
           at lv.digitalmind.portal.FileDownloadServlet.doPost(FileDownloadServlet.java:62)
           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   ```

**FileDownload servlet implementation:**

```
            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                        RestHelper helper = new RestHelper(); //create rest helper class object

                        String docName = request.getParameter("documentName"); //recieving doc name 
                        String docID = request.getParameter("documentID"); //recieving doc id

                        InputStream in = helper.getDocumentRequest(docID); //launching REST to recieve document content by its ID, and we really get this data
                        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

                        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
                        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" + docName + '"' + ".docx");

                        IOUtils.copy(in,out);

                        in.close();
                        out.close();
            }
```

Implementation of function **getDocumentRequest** that receives document content from REST call:

```
              public InputStream getDocumentRequest(String docID) {
                    String restREQ = "MY_REST_URL" + docID + "/content";
                    String basic_auth = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(("SERVICE_LOGIN" + ":" + "SERVICE_PASS").getBytes()));
                    try(  CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                            .build();
                       ) 
                    {
                      HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(restREQ);
                      httpget.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + basic_auth);

                      CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                      try 
                      {
                        return response.getEntity().getContent();
                      } 
                      finally 
                      {
                        response.close();
                      }
                    } 
                    catch(Exception e) 
                    {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  return null;
              }
```

My question is - what i have missed? I feel that i`m really getting document content and there is issue with pushing application to produce it in output Stream so user could download it. Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the REST service ("MY_REST_URL" + docID + "/content) on it's own (using PostMan curl, wget, anything else)? It seems it's having issues reading from the stream returned by response.getEntity().getContent().

Comment: Dear @SimonBerthiaume, thanks for your reply. Commands and their output results: <pre><code>
System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContentLength());
System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContentEncoding());
System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContentType());
System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContent());
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
      
Responses are: 
11309
null
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@3eb3f8c2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
</pre></code>

Comment: I know it will cause a "leak", but can you try to remove the `response.close()` in getDocumentRequest(); I believe it might also close the steam you are trying to read from.